# Set Nested Property Values using Reflections

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've searched throughout but can't find the exact answer to my question. Take for instance the following code:

```
public class Company
{
    private string m_strName;
    private Customer m_objCustomer;

    public Company()
    {
        m_strName = "";
        m_objCustomer = new Customer();
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_strName; }
        set { m_strName = value; }
    }

    public Customer CustomerInformaion
    {
        get { return m_objCustomer; }
        set { m_objCustomer = value; }
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    private string m_strName;
    private Details m_objDetails;


    public Customer()
    {
        m_strName = "";
        m_objDetails = new Details();
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_strName; }
        set { m_strName = value; }
    }

    public Details CustomerDetails
    {
        get { return m_objDetails; }
        set { m_objDetails = value; }
    }
}

public class Details
{
    private string m_strPhoneNumber;
    private string m_strEmailAddress;

    public Details()
    {
        m_strPhoneNumber = "";
        m_strEmailAddress = "";
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return m_strPhoneNumber; }
        set { m_strPhoneNumber = value; }
    }

    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return m_strEmailAddress; }
        set { m_strEmailAddress = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, I have setup a Form that has many text fields where a user can enter information about a customer at a company. One of those fields is the Email Address text field that has a Tag property set to EmailAddress. I want to be able to look at the Tag of the TextBox and iterate through the entire Company object to find a property with a matching Name and Set its value to the Text property of the TextBox. I can locate the property but setting its value has turned out to be quite difficult. Here's what I have thus far:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo info in m_objCompany.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (info.PropertyType != typeof(System.String))
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo info2 in info.PropertyType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (objTextBox.Tag.Equals(info2.Name))
            {
                if (info2.CanWrite)
                {
                    Object objValue = Convert.ChangeType(objTextBox.Text, info.PropertyType);
                    info2.SetValue(m_objCompany, objValue, null);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I run the code I receive an error at ChangeType and/or SetValue. The issue is that the Reflection is stopping at info2 and attempting to set the value to the Type of Details - since it is the parent of the Property EmailAddress.

Any help in determining how to point the SetValue to appropriate property would be helpful and appreciated. As I'm sure you well can guess my class is a GREAT deal larger than the example provided with near 100 properties. Most all are string values which will be entered in manually through TextBox objects. I'm attempting to create one routine that can then be called by all TextBox objects whereby the Tag property of the object could be used to indicate which Property of my class I'm trying to set. From there it is off to XML serialization land.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your innermost line

```
info2.SetValue(m_objCompany, objValue, null);
```

is trying to set value of the inner property (info2), on the outer object. The outer object doesn't have an inner object.

What you probably want, is something like this:

```
    public void Bar(object m_objCompany)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in m_objCompany.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (info.PropertyType != typeof(System.String))
            {
                // Somehow create the outer property
                object outerPropertyValue = info.PropertyType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });

                foreach (PropertyInfo info2 in info.PropertyType.GetProperties())
                {
                    if ("blah" == "blah")
                    {
                        if (info2.CanWrite)
                        {
                            Object innerPropertyValue = Convert.ChangeType("blah", info2.PropertyType);
                            info2.SetValue(outerPropertyValue, innerPropertyValue, null);
                        }
                    }

                }

                info.SetValue(m_objCompany, outerPropertyValue, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

When you come across a property that you want to set, you need to create that property (outerPropertyValue), then setup the properties of that property (via innerPropertyValue), then set the outer property on the original object (m_objCompany).

Comment: Amazing. Such speed and accuracy! THANKS A TON!! That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some code I use for Reflection. In this case you would want to call the `SetValue` method.

```
Reflector.SetValue(TARGET_OBJECT, "Customer.Details.PhoneNumber", "ValueToSet");
```

**UPDATE:** Added the missing ConversionResult struct. Sorry for the omission.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;

namespace YourNamespace
{
  public struct ConversionResult
  {
     public Boolean Success;
     public object ConvertedValue;
  }

  public static class Reflector
  {
    private static BindingFlags DefaultBindings = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute the "codeToExecute" string on the "source" object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Object the code should be executed against</param>
    /// <param name="codeToExecute">Code that should be executed ex. 'Person.Age'</param>
    /// <returns>The result of execute codeToExecute on source</returns>
    public static object GetValue(object source, String codeToExecute)
    {
      ReflectorResult reflectorResult = GetReflectorResult(source, codeToExecute, true, false);
      if (reflectorResult != null)
      {
        return reflectorResult.Value;
      }
      return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the "source" object to the "value" specified in "codeToExecute"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Object the code should be executed against</param>
    /// <param name="codeToExecute">Code that should be executed ex. 'Person.Age'</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value to set the source+codeToExecute to.</param>
    public static Boolean SetValue(object source, String codeToExecute, object value)
    {
      return SetValue(source, codeToExecute, value, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the "source" object to the "value" specified in "codeToExecute"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Object the code should be executed against</param>
    /// <param name="codeToExecute">Code that should be executed ex. 'Person.Age'</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value to set the source+codeToExecute to.</param>
    /// <param name="createIfNotExists">Creates items it cannot find</param>
    public static Boolean SetValue(object source, String codeToExecute, object value, Boolean createIfNotExists)
    {
      Boolean executed = true;

      ReflectorResult reflectorResult = GetReflectorResult(source, codeToExecute, false, createIfNotExists);
      if (reflectorResult != null)
      {
        TypeConverter typeConverter = null;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = reflectorResult.MemberInfo as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
          if (propertyInfo.CanWrite)
          {
            typeConverter = GetTypeConverter(propertyInfo);

            ConversionResult conversionResult = ConvertValue(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType, typeConverter);
            if (conversionResult.Success)
            {
              propertyInfo.SetValue(reflectorResult.PreviousValue, conversionResult.ConvertedValue, reflectorResult.MemberInfoParameters);
            }
            else
            {
              executed = false;
              PentaLogger.LogVerbose("Invalid value: " + value);
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          FieldInfo fieldInfo = reflectorResult.MemberInfo as FieldInfo;
          if (fieldInfo != null)
          {
            typeConverter = GetTypeConverter(fieldInfo);
            ConversionResult conversionResult = ConvertValue(value, fieldInfo.FieldType, typeConverter);
            if (conversionResult.Success)
            {
              fieldInfo.SetValue(reflectorResult.PreviousValue, conversionResult.ConvertedValue);
            }
            else
            {
              executed = false;
              PentaLogger.LogVerbose("Invalid value: " + value);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            // both property and field are invalid
            executed = false;
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        executed = false;
      }

      return executed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the "source" object to the "value" specified in "codeToExecute"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Object the code should be executed against</param>
    /// <param name="codeToExecute">Code that should be executed ex. 'Person.Age'</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value to set the source+codeToExecute to.</param>
    public static void RunDynamicCode(object source, String codeToExecute)
    {
      GetReflectorResult(source, codeToExecute, true, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the method on the "source" object with the passed parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Object the code should be executed against</param>
    /// <param name="methodName">Method to call</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Method Parameters</param>
    public static object ExecuteMethod(object source, String methodName, object[] parameters)
    {
      if (parameters == null)
      {
        parameters = new object[0];
      }

      MethodInfo[] methodInfos = GetMethods(source, methodName);

      foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
      {
        object[] convertedParameters = GetParameters(methodInfo, parameters);
        if (convertedParameters != null)
        {
          return methodInfo.Invoke(source, convertedParameters);
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the method on the "source" object with the passed parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Object the code should be executed against</param>
    /// <param name="methodName">Method to call</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">Method Parameter</param>
    public static object ExecuteMethod(object source, String methodName, object parameter)
    {
      return ExecuteMethod(source, methodName, new object[] { parameter });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the method on the "source" object with no parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Object the code should be executed against</param>
    /// <param name="methodName">Method to call</param>
    public static object ExecuteMethod(object source, String methodName)
    {
      return ExecuteMethod(source, methodName, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies all public properties and fields from source to target
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="target"></param>
    public static void CopyObject(object source, object target)
    {
      if (source != null && target != null)
      {
        Type targetType = target.GetType();
        Type sourceType = source.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = sourceType.GetProperties(DefaultBindings);
        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in properties)
        {
          PropertyInfo targetProperty = targetType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name, sourceProperty.PropertyType);
          if (targetProperty != null && targetProperty.CanRead && targetProperty.CanWrite)
          {
            object value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);
            targetProperty.SetValue(target, value, null);
          }
        }

        FieldInfo[] fields = sourceType.GetFields(DefaultBindings);
        foreach (FieldInfo sourceField in fields)
        {
          FieldInfo targetField = targetType.GetField(sourceField.Name);
          if (targetField != null && targetField.IsPublic)
          {
            object value = sourceField.GetValue(source);
            targetField.SetValue(target, value);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the object to the correct type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to convert</param>
    /// <param name="type">Type to convert to</param>
    /// <returns>Converted value</returns>
    public static ConversionResult ConvertValue(object value, Type type, TypeConverter typeConverter)
    {
      ConversionResult conversionResult = new ConversionResult();
      conversionResult.Success = false;
      if (value != null && type != null)
      {
        Type objectType = value.GetType();
        if (objectType == type)
        {
          conversionResult.Success = true;
          conversionResult.ConvertedValue = value;
        }
        else
        {
          // If there is an explicit type converter use it
          if (typeConverter != null && typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(objectType))
          {
            try
            {
              conversionResult.ConvertedValue = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(value);
              conversionResult.Success = true;
            }
            catch (FormatException) { }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              if (!(e.InnerException is FormatException))
              {
                throw;
              }
            }
          }
          else
          {
            try
            {
              conversionResult.ConvertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, type, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
              conversionResult.Success = true;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException) { }
          }
        }
      }
      return conversionResult;
    }

    public static Boolean CanCreateObect(String classPath, Assembly assembly, params object[] parameters)
    {
      Boolean canCreate = false;
      Type type = Type.GetType(classPath);
      if (type == null)
      {
        String pathWithAssembly = classPath + ", " + assembly.FullName;
        type = Type.GetType(pathWithAssembly);
      }

      if (type != null)
      {
        foreach (ConstructorInfo ci in type.GetConstructors())
        {
          if (ci.IsPublic)
          {
            ParameterInfo[] constructorParameters = ci.GetParameters();
            if (constructorParameters.Length == parameters.Length)
            {
              for(Int32 i=0; i<constructorParameters.Length; i++)
              {                
                object parameter = parameters[i];
                if(parameter == null)
                {
                  continue;
                }

                ParameterInfo pi = constructorParameters[i];
                if (!pi.ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(parameter.GetType()))
                {
                  break;
                }
              }
              canCreate = true;
              break;
            }
          }  
        }       
      }
      return canCreate;
    }

    public static object CreateObject(String classPath, Assembly assembly, params object[] parameters)
    {
      Type type = Type.GetType(classPath);
      if (type == null)
      {
        String pathWithAssembly = classPath + ", " + assembly.FullName;
        type = Type.GetType(pathWithAssembly);
      }

      if (type == null)
      {
        return null;
      }
      return Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private static ReflectorResult GetReflectorResult(object source, String codeToExecute, bool getLastValue, bool createIfNotExists)
    {
      ReflectorResult result = new ReflectorResult(source);

      try
      {
        // Split the code into usable fragments
        String[] codeFragments = SplitCodeArray(codeToExecute);
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < codeFragments.Length; i++)
        {
          // if the value is null we cannot go any deeper so don't waste your time
          if (result.Value == null)
          {
            return result;
          }

          String codeFragment = codeFragments[i];
          result.PreviousValue = result.Value;

          if (codeFragment.Contains("]"))
          {
            ProcessArray(result, codeFragment, createIfNotExists);
          }
          else if (codeFragment.Contains(")"))
          {
            ProcessMethod(result, codeFragment);
          }
          else
          {
            // For set properties we do not need the last value
            bool retrieveValue = getLastValue;
            if (!retrieveValue)
            {
              // If this is not the last one in the array, get it anyway
              retrieveValue = i + 1 != codeFragments.Length;
            }
            ProcessProperty(result, codeFragment, retrieveValue);
          }
        }
      }
      catch (InvalidCodeFragmentException ex)
      {
        PentaLogger.LogVerbose("Invalid Property: '" + codeToExecute + "' Invalid Fragment: '" + ex.Message + "'");
      }

      return result;
    }

    private static String[] SplitCodeArray(String codeToExecute)
    {
      List<String> items = new List<String>();

      Int32 parenAndbracketCount = 0;
      String buffer = "";
      foreach (Char c in codeToExecute.ToCharArray())
      {
        if (c == '.')
        {
          if (buffer.Length > 0)
          {
            items.Add(buffer);
            buffer = "";
          }
          continue;
        }
        else if (c == '[')
        {
          parenAndbracketCount++;
          if (buffer.Length > 0)
          {
            items.Add(buffer);
          }
          buffer = c.ToString();
        }
        else if (c == ']' || c == ')')
        {
          parenAndbracketCount--;
          buffer += c;
          if (buffer.Length > 0)
          {
            items.Add(buffer);
            buffer = "";
          }
        }
        else if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || Char.IsControl(c))
        {
          if (parenAndbracketCount == 0)
          {
            // Skip it
            continue;
          }
          else
          {
            buffer += c;
          }
        }
        else if (c == '(')
        {
          parenAndbracketCount++;
          buffer += c;
        }
        else
        {
          buffer += c;
        }
      }
      if (buffer.Length > 0)
      {
        items.Add(buffer);
      }
      return items.ToArray();
    }

    private static object[] GetParameters(String codeFragment, MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
      String parameters = SplitParametersFromMethod(codeFragment);
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
        return new object[0];

      object[] parameterArray = parameters.Split(',');
      return GetParameters(memberInfo, parameterArray);
    }

    private static object[] GetParameters(MemberInfo memberInfo, object[] parameterArray)
    {
      ParameterInfo[] parameterInfo = null;
      TypeConverter typeConverter = null;

      PropertyInfo propertyInfo = memberInfo as PropertyInfo;
      if (propertyInfo != null)
      {
        parameterInfo = propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters();
        typeConverter = GetTypeConverter(parameterInfo[0]);
      }
      else
      {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = memberInfo as MethodInfo;
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
          parameterInfo = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        }
      }

      if (parameterInfo == null)
      {
        return null;
      }

      object[] returnParameters = new object[parameterInfo.Length];
      for (Int32 i = 0; i < parameterArray.Length; i++)
      {
        ConversionResult converstionResult = ConvertValue(parameterArray[i], parameterInfo[i].ParameterType, typeConverter);
        if (converstionResult.Success)
        {
          returnParameters[i] = converstionResult.ConvertedValue;
        }
        else
        {
          return null;
        }
      }
      return returnParameters;
    }

    private static TypeConverter GetTypeConverter(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type targetType)
    {
      object[] typeConverters = memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TypeConverterAttribute), true);
      if (typeConverters.Length > 0)
      {
        TypeConverterAttribute typeConverterAttribute = (TypeConverterAttribute)typeConverters[0];
        Type typeFromName = Type.GetType(typeConverterAttribute.ConverterTypeName);
        if ((typeFromName != null) && typeof(TypeConverter).IsAssignableFrom(typeFromName))
        {
          return (TypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFromName);
        }
      }
      return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
    }

    private static TypeConverter GetTypeConverter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
      return GetTypeConverter(propertyInfo, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
    }

    private static TypeConverter GetTypeConverter(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
      return GetTypeConverter(fieldInfo, fieldInfo.FieldType);
    }

    private static TypeConverter GetTypeConverter(ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
    {
      return GetTypeConverter(parameterInfo.Member, parameterInfo.ParameterType);
    }

    private static ArrayDefinition GetArrayDefinition(object value, String codeToExecute)
    {
      // All IList classes have an Item property except for System.Array.
      List<MemberInfo> retrieveMemberInfos = new List<MemberInfo>();
      foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in value.GetType().GetProperties(DefaultBindings))
      {
        if (propertyInfo.Name == "Item")
        {
          retrieveMemberInfos.Add(propertyInfo);
        }
      }

      if (retrieveMemberInfos.Count == 0)
      {
        // We didn't find any Item properties so this is probably an Array. Use the GetValue method
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in value.GetType().GetMethods(DefaultBindings))
        {
          if (methodInfo.Name == "GetValue")
          {
            retrieveMemberInfos.Add(methodInfo);
          }
        }
      }

      // Some members have overloaded this[] methods. Find the correct method.
      foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in retrieveMemberInfos)
      {
        object[] parameters = GetParameters(codeToExecute, memberInfo);
        if (parameters != null)
        {
          ArrayDefinition arrayDefinition = new ArrayDefinition();
          arrayDefinition.Parameters = parameters;
          arrayDefinition.RetrieveMemberInfo = memberInfo;
          return arrayDefinition;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    private static void ProcessArray(ReflectorResult result, String codeFragment, Boolean createIfNotExists)
    {
      Int32 failCount = 0;
      ArrayDefinition arrayDefinition = GetArrayDefinition(result.Value, codeFragment);
      if (arrayDefinition != null)
      {
        // If this is anything but System.Array we need to call a Property
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = arrayDefinition.RetrieveMemberInfo as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
        SetPropertyInfoValue:
          try
          {
            object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(result.Value, arrayDefinition.Parameters);
            result.SetResult(value, propertyInfo, arrayDefinition.Parameters);
          }
          catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
          {
            failCount++;
            if (ex.InnerException is ArgumentOutOfRangeException && failCount == 1 && createIfNotExists)
            {
              if (CreateArrayItem(result, arrayDefinition))
              {
                goto SetPropertyInfoValue;
              }
            }

            // Tried to fix it but failed. Blow up
            result.Clear();
            throw new InvalidCodeFragmentException(codeFragment);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          // System.Array has a Method to call
          MethodInfo methodInfo = arrayDefinition.RetrieveMemberInfo as MethodInfo;
          if (methodInfo != null)
          {
            try
            {
              // We can't support dynamically creating array items
              object value = methodInfo.Invoke(result.Value, arrayDefinition.Parameters);
              result.SetResult(value, methodInfo, arrayDefinition.Parameters);
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException)
            {
              result.Clear();
              throw new InvalidCodeFragmentException(codeFragment);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        result.Clear();
        throw new InvalidCodeFragmentException(codeFragment);
      }
    }

    private static Boolean CreateArrayItem(ReflectorResult result, ArrayDefinition arrayDefinition)
    {
      Type resultType = result.Value.GetType();
      Type containedType = null;
      if (resultType.IsArray)
      {
        containedType = resultType.GetElementType();
      }
      else
      {
        containedType = resultType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
      }

      object newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(containedType);
      if (!resultType.IsArray)
      {
        MethodInfo[] methods = GetMethods(result.Value, "Insert");
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methods)
        {
          object[] temp = new object[arrayDefinition.Parameters.Length + 1];
          arrayDefinition.Parameters.CopyTo(temp, 0);
          temp[arrayDefinition.Parameters.Length] = newInstance;

          object[] parameters = GetParameters(methodInfo, temp);
          if (parameters != null)
          {
            methodInfo.Invoke(result.Value, parameters);
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    private static void ProcessProperty(ReflectorResult result, String codeFragment, bool retrieveValue)
    {
      // This is just a regular property
      PropertyInfo propertyInfo = result.Value.GetType().GetProperty(codeFragment, DefaultBindings);
      if (propertyInfo != null)
      {
        object value = result.Value;
        if (retrieveValue)
        {
          value = propertyInfo.GetValue(result.Value, null);
          result.SetResult(value, propertyInfo, null);
        }
        result.SetResult(value, propertyInfo, null);
      }
      else
      {
        // Maybe it is a field
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = result.Value.GetType().GetField(codeFragment, DefaultBindings);

        if (fieldInfo != null)
        {
          object value = result.Value;
          if (retrieveValue)
          {
            value = fieldInfo.GetValue(result.Value);
          }
          result.SetResult(value, fieldInfo, null);
        }
        else
        {
          // This item is missing, log it and set the value to null
          result.Clear();
          throw new InvalidCodeFragmentException(codeFragment);
        }
      }
    }

    private static void ProcessMethod(ReflectorResult result, String codeFragment)
    {
      // This is just a regular property
      String methodName = codeFragment.Substring(0, codeFragment.IndexOf('('));
      MethodInfo[] methodInfos = GetMethods(result.Value, methodName);

      foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
      {
        object[] parameters = GetParameters(codeFragment, methodInfo);
        if (parameters != null)
        {
          object value = methodInfo.Invoke(result.Value, parameters);
          result.SetResult(value, null, null);
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    private static String SplitParametersFromMethod(String codeFragment)
    {
      char startCharacter = '[';
      char endCharacter = ']';

      if (codeFragment.EndsWith(")", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
      {
        // This is a function
        startCharacter = '(';
        endCharacter = ')';
      }

      Int32 startParam = codeFragment.IndexOf(startCharacter) + 1;
      if (startParam < 1)
        return null;

      Int32 endParam = codeFragment.IndexOf(endCharacter);
      if (endParam < 0)
        return null;

      return codeFragment.Substring(startParam, endParam - startParam).Trim();
    }

    private static MethodInfo[] GetMethods(object value, String methodName)
    {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName))
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("methodName");
      }

      if (value == null)
      {
        return new MethodInfo[0];
      }

      List<MethodInfo> methodInfos = new List<MethodInfo>();
      foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in value.GetType().GetMethods(DefaultBindings))
      {
        if (methodInfo.Name == methodName)
        {
          methodInfos.Add(methodInfo);
        }
      }
      return methodInfos.ToArray();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Helper Classes
    private class ArrayDefinition
    {
      public MemberInfo RetrieveMemberInfo { get; set; }

      public object[] Parameters { get; set; }
    }

    private class ReflectorResult
    {
      public ReflectorResult(object startValue)
      {
        SetResult(startValue, null, null);
      }
      public MemberInfo MemberInfo { get; private set; }
      public object[] MemberInfoParameters { get; private set; }
      public object PreviousValue { get; set; }
      public object Value { get; private set; }

      public void SetResult(object value, MemberInfo memberInfo, object[] memberInfoParameters)
      {
        Value = value;
        MemberInfo = memberInfo;
        MemberInfoParameters = memberInfoParameters;
      }

      public void Clear()
      {
        MemberInfo = null;
        Value = null;
        PreviousValue = null;
      }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1064:ExceptionsShouldBePublic")]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1032:ImplementStandardExceptionConstructors")]
    private class InvalidCodeFragmentException : Exception
    {
      public InvalidCodeFragmentException(String invalidFragment)
        : base(invalidFragment)
      {

      }
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: This may have worked but doesn't seem to compile at all in .NET 1.1 which is what I'm forced to use at the moment in order to be compatible with the remainder of the project. It looks interesting though.

Comment: @ShaunBowe +1. But it seems you forgot `ConversionResult` definition

Comment: @ShaunBowe, you need to add the ConversionResult class.

Comment: I added the ConversionResult class. Sorry for missing that for so long.

Comment: Thanks for that @ShaunBowe. I tried using the CopyObject method. I discovered that the fields are not cloned, only the references are copied. You can replace this methos with the following code:
public static T Clone<T>(T source) {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
             var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source), deserializeSettings); }

Comment: It should. You would have to use Complex.Property

Comment: The Reflector does not generate the "outer"/parent class if not instantiated yet. In your example this would mean, that "Details" remains null. Furthermore, SetValue() does not continue if there is no Conversion available, so it will stop even before handling "Details"